# How do I omit variable names from URI when submitting an html form?

Tags: php, html

I have the following search form on my php project :

```
<form method="get" action="/search/" />
  <input type="text" name="q" />
  <input type=submit>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, the URI is mysite.com/search/?q=sample+query , but I want it to be like mysite.com/search/sample+query/ . Is there a way to achieve this within php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. What happens is, the form gets submitted to *search/* like

> search/?q=search+query

and from there, we redirect the user to

> search/search+query/

and process the query there.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Simply add a
>
> ```
> .htaccess
> ```
>
> file and edit its content like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) index\.php?q=$1
```

> 2) Rename your php file as
>
> ```
> index.php
> ```

Comment: But this just does the same as before (mysite.com/search/?q=sample+query) . BTW, I've already written a RewriteRule to direct all requests to a route.php file. I'm considering "including" the appropriate php script in route.php as per the URI... /search/?q=sample+query does work, but /search/sample+query/ looks more aesthetic and that's why I asked